# Grails gradle: How to set System Property

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle

May I know why I'm unable to set the System Property with the systemProperty method when using  the grails-gradle-plugin?

My build.gradle as follows:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
  }
}

version "0.1"
group "example"

apply plugin: "grails"

repositories {
  grails.central() //creates a maven repo for the Grails Central repository (Core libraries and plugins)
}

grails {
  grailsVersion = '2.3.5'
  groovyVersion = '2.1.9'
  springLoadedVersion '1.1.3'
}

dependencies {
  bootstrap "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.50" // No container is deployed by default, so add this
  compile 'org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2' // Just an example of adding a Grails plugin
}

test {
  println "I'm in the test"
  //Could not find method systemProperty() for arguments [geb.env, sauce] on root project
  systemProperty 'geb.env', 'sauce'//Fails

}
```

In the test task, I get the following error when i run `$gradle grails-test`: 
Could not find method systemProperty() for arguments [geb.env, sauce] on root project..."

Is this a problem with the grails-gradle plugin since other plugins like "java" allows me to use setProperty? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried System.setProperty('geb.env', 'sauce')?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct: there's no systemProperty() method.

As Joshua Moore comments, this should work:

```
test {
  println "I'm in the test"
  System.setProperty 'geb.env', 'sauce'
}
```